# Mono.Cecil add a new void method

Tags: vb.net, mono

I need to create a new void method in the IL code, but I do not know how to state the type Void in the statement "returnType as Mono.Cecil.TypeReference" in the field ?????? below in the code

```
Dim MethodAtt = Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Public Or Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.HideBySig Or Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.SpecialName Or Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName

Dim newm As New MethodDefinition("nuovo_method", MethodAtt, ??????)
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `c#` tag for this. `vb.net` is enough.

Comment: thanks...my first question :-)

Comment: @MessereBlind don't answer your own question in the question. Add an answer for that, then accept it.

Comment: Thanks! I have to learn ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I have SOLVED it!

you have to import the Void type from your moduledefinition

```
Dim name = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(currentname)
.
.
.
Dim voidtype As TypeReference = name.Import(GetType(Void))
Dim newm As New MethodDefinition("nuovo_method", MethodAtt, voidtype )
```